# jQuery show/hide one div if another has value

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<div class="field-name-new">
  <div class="field-label">New</div>
  <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item">0</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to show div.field-label only if div.field-item has value 1 and hide it if it has value 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing there is only one `div.field-item` inside each `div.field-items` this should work:

```
$('.field-items').each(function(i,el)
{
    var field_item = $(el);
    if(field_item.text() == 1)
        $(this).prev().show();
    else
        $(this).prev().hide();
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/zsA7W/

Comment: Love this one cause it will append to any kind of elements i have with those keys - and i have them a lot ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
var $item = $('.field-item');

if ($item.text() == 0)​​ {
    $item.parent().siblings('.field-label').hide();
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/FTbBT/

Comment: Note: That will only hide the element, it won't show the element if it's already hidden.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`toggle` method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to show or hide an element depending on a condition:

```
$('.field-label').toggle($('.field-item').text() == '1');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.field-item').each(function(){
       if($(this).text() == 0){
            $(this).parent().prev().hide();
       }else{
           $(this).parent().prev().show();
    }
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.field-label').each(function() {
       $(this).css('display', $(this).next('.field-items').find('.field-item').is(':contains("1")') ? 'block' : 'none');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HackedByChinese/kXdat/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) with a boolean flag

```
$('.field-name-new').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find('.field-label').toggle(!!$this.find('.field-item').text())
});
```

I created an `each` in case you have more than one `.field-name-new` block

Answer (score 1):

**It works fine !**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($(".field-item").html() == '0'){    
    $("div.field-label").hide();
    }
});​
```

**Updated Jsfiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/m4BTd/4/ test it by changing value in `<div class="field-item">0</div>`  and click `Run`